# how to put a image to left or right of a edit text in constraint layout android like below

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How to maintain the responsive layout by replacing `marginTop` in `constraint-layout`?

[image: like login image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this into `EditText`.

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" // pass image name
android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
```

Comment: it work. now how to make drawable image to small size according to textbox?

Comment: it create icon according to device.

Comment: https://icons8.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to `EditText`

```
android:drawableStart="@drawable/image_name"
```

For Lower Api version

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image_name"
```